# Using dotnet String.Format to save data to database, fails

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I come from a scripting world, so .NET is very new to me. I have the following string format that I am using to save data to a database. I'm probably missing something very simple.

```
Dim str = String.Format("INSERT INTO invoice_labels(WOpre, WOsuf, ModelNumber, SupplierID, BoxNo, BoxQty, Stamp, MachineName) VALUES({0}, {1}, '{2}', {3}, {4}, {5}, '{6}', '{7}')", WoPre_TB.Text, WoSuf_TB.Text, ModelPN_TB.Text, SupplierID_TB.Text, BoxNumber_TB.Text, FullBoxQty_TB.Text, FormattedDate, MachineName)
```

Columns values 3, 7 and 8 are all strings and the rest are integer values. MySQL is complaining about the date column (FormattedDate), but when I echo the string, the SQL statement is good. I can manually recreate the insert statement according to what's echo'd and the data are saved.

Can someone shed some light for me, please?

Comment: All you need to do is use SQL parameters for the query and then it will work properly.

Comment: "complaining about" ...in what way exactly? Tell us your exact error message please. And give us a sample of the finished value of `str`, to go with it. But yes you should be using parameterised queries...this is potentially wide open to SQL injection attacks at it stands. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html for an example (assuming you're using the mysql connector rather than something else like entity framework or whatever)

Comment: There is an example of using SQL parameters with an INSERT statement in a previous answer of mine at [error in my vb program of cmd.executenonquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52235541/1115360).

Comment: As the date is causing the problem, are you providing the date in the correct format for MySQL? And if the column name of "Stamp" suggests that you are just storing "now" (as in a timestamp), wouldn't it be easier to leave that column out of the query and have the column default set to be current date/time?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Because I'm so new to dot Net, an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: He's already given you an example...did you read the link? So did I, for that matter. Or are you wanting an example which demonstrates something else? P.S. You haven't edited your question as per my request either, to show an example the finished query which fails, and the exact error message. Perhaps that would shed some more light on exactly what you need to change. Maybe you need to send the date in a different format, or, as droopsnoot suggested, just let it set default value. These are the kinds of details which are missing from your description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. Do not use `String.Format`.
You will need to check the datatype in the database for each field and correct `MySqlDbType` and convesion of the `.Text` property of the TextBoxes accordingly.
Each input by the user should be validated before setting the .Value property of the parameter.

```
    Dim str = "INSERT INTO invoice_labels(WOpre, WOsuf, ModelNumber, SupplierID, BoxNo, BoxQty, Stamp, MachineName) VALUES(@WOpre, @WOsuf, @ModelNumber, @SupplierID, @BoxNo, @BoxQty, @Stamp, @MachineName);"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WOpre", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(WoPre_TB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WOsuf", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(WoSuf_TB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModelNumber", MySqlDbType.String).Value = ModelPN_TB.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(SupplierID_TB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BoxNo", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(BoxNumber_TB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BoxQty", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(FullBoxQty_TB.Text)cmd.Parameters.Add("", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value =
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stamp", MySqlDbType.String).Value = FormattedDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MachineName", MySqlDbType.String).Value = MachineName
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```